# How do we prevent the bootstrapper to install prerequisites?

Tags: windows-installer

Currently We are installing prequisties softwares using the bootstrapper. So i want to install the prerequisties without  using the Bootstrapper ?. Whether it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your using a Visual Studio project but you could create a custom action to install prerequisits.  Here is a link that was useful to me in the past http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx